# Embed JavaScript in GitHub README.md

Tags: javascript, github, markdown

I want to embed a tweet in a GitHub README file. Markdown should support this, however when I add the code that is copied from the tweet the JavaScript doesn't get rendered.

Example:

`<blockquote>...</blockquote>

<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can embed JavaScript in Markdown.

Comment: You do realize that if I could embed JavaScript into this comment I can go around looking for new questions, help you downvote a couple questions, post a new question for you, change your name or profile picture, and get you banned, right? You think allowing any script on your website is a good idea? You'll more likely embed tweets by asking Github to enable markdown embeds or something.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Allowing javascript from third parties directly on a website has huge XSS attacks implications. Someone could use javascript code for example to grab the cookies associated to any visitor's github accounts and forward them to a malicious entity.

There's also the nuisance potential, as having access to javascript means having access to the CPU of the visitor and being able to do things like pop-ups or blinking text.

As such it's natural that javascript isn't supported in READMEs. Markdown **may** have a way of doing it, but it'll never be allowed on a website like GitHub.

However, you can do it on your project's [github page](http://pages.github.com/), if you have one, since it doesn't belong to the main github website and the domain is not the same.

Comment: well if you own the readme then why would you be protecting yourself from making blinking text? With that line of logic we should disable javascript on websites because the owner of the website might "able to do things like pop-ups or blinking text"

Comment: JavaScript could also alter GitHub's login form's action such that logging in sends the user's credentials to your own malicious server.  However this could be mitigated by forcing js to run inside an iframe as D1plo1d suggested.

Comment: they recently allow you to customize your profile home page, so I was trying to load a JavaScript game into it; [source](https://youtu.be/-otyb0ngsa4)

Answer (score 17):

As a follow up to coyotte508's answer (sorry, not enough points to reply directly):

If Github were to enable such a feature they could use iFrames as an effective measure against XSS in the same way ReadTheDocs does.

EDIT: Also you might want to check out readthedocs.org as an alternative to a Github README.md. They support embedding javascript in rst files.