# Can speaker deck slide be embedded in README file of github?

Tags: javascript, github, markdown

I have a presentation slide in speakerdeck and i want to embed it in README.md page of github repository. is it possible to do so?

Here is my embedded script from speakerdeck

`<script async class="speakerdeck-embed" data-id="3586d5e7f45ce6" data-ratio="1.33333333333333" src="//speakerdeck.com/assets/embed.js"></script>`

**README.md**

> ###Introduction
>
> This is a introduction of the app ...
>
> ###Slide
>
> `<script async class="speakerdeck-embed" data-id="3586d6f45ce6"
>   data-ratio="1.33333333333333"
>   src="//speakerdeck.com/assets/embed.js"></script>`

slide does not appear on README section of repo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't and you shouldn't mostly because of security reasons.

GitHub won't allow the execution of an external script.

Check this answer: [Embed JavaScript in GitHub README.md](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340803/embed-javascript-in-github-readme-md)

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot embed scripts inside GitHub's markdown.

Being able to embed scripts would lead to XSS (Cross-site scripting) insecurities, therefore it is not possible by GitHub's design, and for good reason.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to add scripts to markdown.
Mark down can be only used for text formatting and not more.

Here is what allowed to use:
[image]

---

#### What can you still do?

You can still embed images like you see here on this answer. So convert your slides to images and embed them

Answer (score 0):

Everything said above is true but I wanted to add one additional piece of information.

Even though `README` will not display the embedded slide but if this repo is converted into *[Github Page](https://pages.github.com/)* then the same README will be rendered perfectly and it will display the speakerdeck slide as well.