# How to play sounds in github?

Tags: javascript, html, github

I was making a github repository with a HTLM5 file and a mp3 file.

On the html file i writed:

```
<script>
var audio = new Audio('sound.mp3');
audio.play();
</script>
```

And then i uploaded in the repository a mp3 file, imagine if the file name was `sound.mp3`.

Here's what the files look like:

**index.html**

**sound.mp3**

The problem is that the HTML script i made is not playing the sound on the github page.

I'm 100% sure that i have the volume up but it dosn't play.

What can i do to make it play the sound in the repository files?

Also i tried using images and looks like the html can get the img file in the repository but not sounds.

Comment: What do you mean by "github page"? Do you mean a GitHub pages website or your project's GitHub repo?

Comment: Github website.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub appears to serve the audio with a video tag, if you go to the link to your audio file you will see something like this:

```
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
    <source src="https://user.github.io/project/audio/sound.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</video>
```

A bypass I've found is to link to the raw mp3 file available on the repository side. If you navigate in the code repository to the audio file, you should see a link that says 'View Raw'. If you copy the link address, it will look something like this:

```
https://github.com/user/project/blob/main/audio/sound.mp3?raw=true
```

You can drop this in natively in your code like so:

```
<script>
    var audio = new Audio('https://github.com/user/project/blob/main/audio/sound.mp3?raw=true');
    audio.play();
</script>
```

One note of caution, there are some built-in blocks on audio autoplay with some browsers such that you need to trigger the playing with a user event like a click.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a sounds file on your repository this is not working like that. Put the audio files on the same level with the index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed `<script>` tags into READMEs because of XSS attacks.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340803/embed-javascript-in-github-readme-md) answer and [this](https://github.github.com/gfm/#html-block) from the GitHub docs for more information.

Comment: OP is talking about an html file not a .md readme file

Comment: I'm not talking about a md file but an html

Comment: @Helloman Try going to `your_site.github.io/sound.mp3` in your browser and see if that returns anything. Also look in the developer console and see if there are any errors.