# How do I embed Expo Snacks in Markdown document

Tags: github, expo, markdown

could someone please tell me how I could embed my Expo Snack in a Markdown file? Because I want to make a documentation kind of thing for my project. And I wanna embed a Snack in it.

###### What I've tried so far that does not work...

```markdown
# MARKDOWN CODE 
---------------
<div 
data-snack-id="@jothamsamuel/tsst" 
data-snack-platform="web" 
data-snack-preview="true" 
data-snack-theme="dark" 
style="overflow:hidden;background:#212121;border:1px solid var(--color-border);border-radius:4px;height:505px;width:100%"
>
</div>
<script async src="https://snack.expo.dev/embed.js"></script>
```

> PS:  I have tried `iframe` but it did not work.

Thank you!

Comment: Not possible. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340803/embed-javascript-in-github-readme-md