# <script> tag not working in svg when mention in markdown

Tags: javascript, svg

Consider I own the domain https://example.com. I have a file `test.svg` with the contents of:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle id="circle" cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>

  <script>
  const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  let color='red';
  if (params.has('color')) {
    color = params.get('color');
  }

  document.getElementById('circle').setAttribute('fill', color);
  </script>
</svg>
```

When I visit https://example.com/test.svg?color=blue, the circle shows the color blue, and when I visit https://example.com/test.svg?color=green, the circle shows the color green.

When I use `![img](https://example.com/test.svg?color=blue)` in [markdown](https://markdownlivepreview.com), the circle shows black.

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Works fine https://codepen.io/KonradLinkowski/pen/GRdVVgj?editors=1111&color=blue

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I know, but it doesn't work in markdown...

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Thanks! That does help. What is a work-around, though?

Comment: I guess that you are trying to use it in readme on github https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340803/embed-javascript-in-github-readme-md

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I'm actually using it on a different website that supports markdown. How can I use a workaround such that the "fill" element of the rectangle is determined by the search parameter?

Comment: I guess that's just impossibe

Comment: @KonradLinkowski It works [in this project](https://github.com/anuraghazra/github-readme-stats). Somehow the SVG image is being created with query parameters, and the image works in markdown. I'm confused about how the person who made that repository is making it work.

Comment: The image is generated on the backend

Comment: @KonradLinkowski How can I do that myself? I know it uses JavaScript... a link to a guide would be really helpful on what I'm trying to do. Thanks once again for all your help!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Introduction

Comment: The issue is that the JavaScript will not run when the SVG is displayed using a n image element `<img>`. You need to use the `<object>` or the `<embed>` element to display  dynamic or interactive SVGs.